# Compiled package and dependency management

Tags: installation, package-management, aptitude

I have a package that depends on squid 3.2. I want to replace squid 3.2 with source compiled version of squid 3.3 beta (which is not available in repository). When I remove squid 3.2, the depending package is also getting removed.

- How can I mark the squid 3.2 dependency as manually resolved?
- Is that the purpose of the command `aptitude umarkauto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do that is to update Squid package itself with a new upstream version, using [Debian package management system](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/update.en.html).

You can also remove Squid package and its configuration by typing in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge squid
```

As is, it will not remove any dependency in a automatic way.

Comment: `apt-get purge` did not work for me. But I was able to update it using the package management system by replacing old squid source with new source archive. Thanks.